# Run two Redux Actions consecutively + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, promise, async-await

I'm quite new to Typescript and I'm trying to dispatch two API calls to a database. The second one should only run once the first one is resolved. The solution should work with Redux-Thunk (not Redux Saga). I have tried async/await and promises without success. I couldn't find any useful answeres in other posts.

**First Action**

```js
  private placeOrder(addressId?: number, projectId?: number) {
     this.props.dispatch(
       requestAPIActions.load<RequestApiHttpPayload>('order', {
         url: '/orders/place-order?addressId=' + addressId + '&projectId=' + projectId,
         queryType: false,
         options: {
           method: 'POST',
         }
       })
     );
   }
```

**Second Action**

```js
private deleteGuest(id: number) {
    this.props.dispatch(
      requestAPIActions.load<RequestApiHttpPayload>('client', {
        url: `/clients/${id}`,
        queryType: false,
        options: {
          method: 'DELETE',
        }
      }));
  }
```

**Edit**

requestAPIActions.load is:

```js
 declare const requestAPIActions: {
    LOAD_REQUEST: string;
 
    /**
     * Redux action to dispatch the initial request to the URL and
     * by using the given config.
     * @alias requestAPIActions.load
     * @param {String} requestId Id that describes the dispached request
     * @param {Object} payload Url and Config for Axios promise
     * @returns {Object} FSA<string, {}, RequestApiMeta>
     */
    load<Payload>(requestId: string, payload: Payload, update?: boolean): import("flux-standard-action").FluxStandardAction<string, {}, RequestApiMeta>;
```

This is where I start to loose understanding of what exactly is happening.

Comment: What does `requestAPIActions.load` do? In particular, is it a thunk that returns a promise?

Comment: Can you show where and how you're wanting to dispatch these actions and API calls?

Comment: @NicholasTower Assuming requestAPIActions.load is a thunk that **returns** a promise you could make another thunk: `const combined = args => (dispatch,getState) => thunk1(args)(dispatch,getState).then(()=>thunk2(args)(dispatch,getState))`

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution would be to dispatch the second action in the `then` block of the first.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) from the redux-thunk docs:

```js
// Meet thunks.
// A thunk in this context is a function that can be dispatched to perform async
// activity and can dispatch actions and read state.
// This is an action creator that returns a thunk:
function makeASandwichWithSecretSauce(forPerson) {
  // We can invert control here by returning a function - the "thunk".
  // When this function is passed to `dispatch`, the thunk middleware will intercept it,
  // and call it with `dispatch` and `getState` as arguments.
  // This gives the thunk function the ability to run some logic, and still interact with the store.
  return function(dispatch) {
    return fetchSecretSauce().then(
      (sauce) => dispatch(makeASandwich(forPerson, sauce)),
      (error) => dispatch(apologize('The Sandwich Shop', forPerson, error)),
    );
  };
}

// Thunk middleware lets me dispatch thunk async actions
// as if they were actions!

store.dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('Me'));
```

Answer (score 0):

if both actions are a promise why don't you just run

```
Promise.all([dispatch(action1(), dispatch(action2()])
.then(([res1,res2]) => console.log(res1,res2)
```